# Why are the only the states 0 and 2 present in line 8?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lr-grammar

LR Parsing:

[image: LR parsing]

LR Parsing Table:

[image: LR Parsing Table]

In line 7, we reduce by `T->T*F`.

And State 7 on T does not have any transition.

In line 8, why do we have only the states *0* and *2*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At step 7, we reduce `T→T*F`, which means that:

1. We pop the right-hand side off of the stack, leaving only the state 0 corresponding to symbol `$`.
2. We consult the goto transitions of state 0 (the new top of the stack) for the left-hand symbol `T`. That says we should goto state 2.
3. We push the new state 2 onto the stack along with the associated symbol `T`.

At the end, the stack is `0 2` with symbols `$ T`, as shown at step 8.

This is well-described in the text and pseudocode algorithms of the excellent book from which those charts were copied.